# How should I govern write access to local Sites directory?

Tags: security, permissions, osx-snow-leopard

I'm currently doing some web dev on osx and I need to give netbeans and apache write access to my local Sites directory, at the moment only one of them has that right (netbeans) should I modify group rights and add apache to the group or look into creating an ACL (never done that before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a single-user desktop development environment running a local apache instance (listening locally for testing), just `chmod 777` the directory and be done with it.  In production this would be a more complex issue, though I suspect netbeans wouldn't be writing to a production directory (I hope!)

Comment: yeah you're right, but I may need to debug the site remotely later. That will be on a linux server though but I guess the access issues will be different then.